# Adobe Illustrator cs5 svg file size

Tags: svg, adobe-illustrator

Hello I have issue with size of `svg`.

When I have some texts on canvas, for example:

```
Text1
Text2
Text3
```

I need to save each `text` into `svg`. So I select `Text1` with Artboard tool and save. Resolution size is 5kb. But when I delete Text2 and `Text3` from canvas and save `Text1`, then `svg` has about 1.2kb.

Is some way how to achieve smaller size without deleting objects? I have tried to put texts into layers and hide them, but it does not works.

Answer (score 0):

Try and use this online SVG cleanup optimizer:

https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/

It has many options to clean up Illustrator code for a smaller SVG file size.

You can either paste your markup or upload a SVG file.

Just some other useful tips:

- remove unneeded whitespace
- remove unneeded tags, like nested `<g>` tags
- decrease decimals as much as possible
- use transforms, instead of creating other paths, shapes or points
- remove attributes that are not needed especially if including your SVG tag inside an HTML page
- remove unwanted namespace URI if including in HTML page.
- remove the doctype and xml tag included in the SVG file if including in an HTML page
- remove any hidden vector pointer
- maybe using flat colors instead gradients and blurs.
- convert inline styles to a  tag for CSS
- optimize and any external images, png is preferable use [tinypng.com](http://tinypng.com/)
- If your SVG is just used as an image, weigh the cost of it as a regular PNG, vs as an SVG

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Rob .. thanks i forgot about that, i added some other useful tips, i stand corrected Good Sir :)

Answer (score 0):

Hiding a layer does not remove it from the svg code, it just sets the display on the group (layer) to "none", the points are all still represented in the code. This is intended functionality of an SVG file. If you want a smaller file size, you really need to remove the elements from the file before you save.